# Reactive Extension, wrap third party API event - zero copy?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, zero-copy

I have a third party API that I do not have the source to. I instantiate a callback to an event like this:

```
using namespace API; // This is where APIClient lives

namespace TestApiClientUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        APIClient apiClient = new APICLient();
        apiClient.QuoteUpdated += api_ClientUpdated;

        private void api_ClientUpdated(object sender, string s, double b, double a)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How do I wrap this into an Rx Observable.FromEvent?

Also, is there a way to do it so the overhead of the wraps copy are as little (zero-copy) as possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's define a struct to store the event args.

```
struct QuoteUpdate
{
    public string S { get; private set; }
    public double B { get; private set; }
    public double A { get; private set; }
    public QuoteUpdate(string s, double b, double a) : this()
    {
        S = s;
        B = b;
        A = a;
    }
}
```

Now we can define an `IObservable<QuoteUpdate>` as follows.

```
var quoteUpdates = Observable.FromEvent<ApiQuoteHandler, QuoteUpdate>(
    emit => (_, s, b, a) => emit(new QuoteUpdate(s, b, a)),
    handler => apiClient.QuoteUpdated += handler,
    handler => apiClient.QuoteUpdated -= handler);
```

The first lambda defines a mapping from `Action<QuoteUpdate>` to `ApiQuoteHandler`.  The action, called `emit`, is what actually broadcasts a value to the subscribers of the observable we are defining.  Think of calling `emit(value);` as something like `foreach (var subscriber in subscribers) { subscriber.OnNext(value); }`.

The reason we need this first mapping is because the actual underlying event only knows how to subscribe and unsubscribe `ApiQuoteHandler` instances.  The second and third lambdas are of type `Action<ApiQuoteHandler`. They are called on subscription and unsubscription, respectively.

When an `IObserver<QuoteUpdate> observer` subscribes to the `IObservable<QuoteUpdate>` we have defined, this is what happens:

1. `observer.OnNext` (of type `Action<QuoteUpdate>`) is passed into our first lambda as the variable `emit`. This creates an `ApiQuoteHandler` that wraps the `observer`.
2. The `ApiQuoteHandler` is then passed into our second lambda as the variable `handler`. The `handler` subscribes to the `QuoteUpdated` event on your `apiClient`.
3. The `IDisposable` returned from `Subscribe` method on our `IObservable<QuoteUpdate>` contains a reference to the `ApiQuoteHandler` that was created by the first of our three lambdas.
4. When at a later time this `IDisposable` is disposed, the third lambda is called with the same `ApiQuoteHandler` from before, unsubscribing from the underlying event.

Because you need a single `IObservable<T>` for some `T` yet you have event args `(s, b, a)`, you must define some struct or class to store the three values. I would not worry about the cost of copying a `string` reference and two `double` values.

Comment: I don't understand your example. What is handler? Visual Studio 2012 gives an error on the emit line "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement. await, and new object expressions can be used in a statement"

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 gives an error on the emit line "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement. await, and new object expressions can be used in a statement"

Comment: On += handler, I get an Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestApiClientUI.Form1.QuoteUpdatedDelegate' to 'Api.ApiQuoteHandler' C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Api_csharp_example\TestApiClientUI\Form1.cs 99 54 TestApiClientUI

Comment: On the struct, the compiler gives Error 1 Backing field for automatically implemented property 'TestApiClientUI.Form1.QuoteUpdate.A' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer. C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MtApi_csharp_example\TestApiClientUI\Form1.cs 58 20 TestApiClientUI

Comment: I fixed the struct problem but still have the problem on the emit line and the += handler line

Comment: @Ivan I apologize for the confusion. The code I wrote was browser code so I hadn't worked out the little problems. Please see my edited answer. All I've done is add the "`: this()`" in the struct and replaced `QuoteUpdatedDelegate` with `ApiQuoteHandler`.  Though I didn't say it explicitly, `QuoteUpdatedDelegate` was just meant to be a placeholder for the type of your `ApiClient.QuoteUpdated` event.  I had no way of knowing what its type was, so I just made up a name that sounded close enough.

Comment: @Ivan I've also added some explanation about what the three lambdas are actually doing.

Comment: Try this in visual studio : Place your mouse next to the first handler and double push tab..It should create a "handler" , a method that is ready to receive the quoteUpdated stream.

Comment: @FxMzt Yes, but that would just be an event handler. @Ivan is asking about how to wrap his event as an `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: I think he didnt "refactor" the handler method ..He just pasted your solution (which looks fine to me).

Comment: @FxMzt Yep, that's correct. :) After my edit (now that he revealed the name of his event type) he can just copy paste, but hopefully now that I've added some explanation he can understand why it was actually working code and just needed some modification on his part.

Comment: Thanks, that is closer. But there is no such type ApiQuoteHandler ?

Comment: @Ivan What is the type of your `QuoteUpdated` event on your `ApiClient`? Use whatever type that is instead of `ApiQuoteHandler`. I can't guess the type because you haven't shown it.